# gmail application logout

Tags: gmail, google-account

I let my friends log into my gmail app to check their mail, and have since, have NOT been able to get rid of their accounts. I'm sick of seeing their names and I'm sick of being tempted to read their inboxes ;P

PLEASE tell me there's a non-factory reset option to log just the two of them out for now, or a way to reset the whole app - I know I have to log myself completely out, but I can't even find this option and I feel Android-ignorant. HELP PLZ - I have an HTC 4G LTE, ftr.

Answer (score 2):

You don't manage the accounts within the Gmail app, but rather at the OS level.

You need to go to `Settings > Accounts` on your phone and remove the accounts from there.

Comment: But you could always have one little peek at their email; just to see what they're saying about you!